# Custom XIB not loaded issue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, subview

In my universal app i have added one empty xib for iphone(ipad app converted into universal), then i have added 1 view and added a button but its not display properly in simulator.

Xib design
[image]

simulator

[image]

please guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: You need to set an autoresizing mask on the button.

Comment: yes, As per Junaid said , Change the value of Status bar in Xib file. As from you question in Simulator there is a Status bar but in Xib there is no statusbar that is Only the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your xib and change status Bar value from none to Gray  [image]